# Can we use advanced instead of postponed in a sentence for communicating that a date has been postponed

Tags: meaning

I would like to know if

The training dates have been advanced by a day .

The training dates have been postponed by a day.

Do they mean the same?

Comment: Have you looked up "advance (verb)" in a dictionary? If you do, I think you'll find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the opposite. Postponed means moved back (later) and advanced means moved up (earlier).